# Bi-directional synchronization between local SQL Server 2005 and a SQL Azure using SQL Data Sync

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, azure-sql-database

I need to synchronize an Sql Server 2005 database in an SQL Azure database. In other posts I've read that I can do this using Sql Data Sync but I don't know if SQL Data Sync can make the synchronizations that I need without exceeding their limitations. This is the exact process I need to do:
First: synchronize 1 table from Azure to Sql Server.
Second: Execute some Store procedures in the SQL Server 2005 instance.
And third: Synchronize various tables from Sql Server to Azure sequentially.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> First: synchronize 1 table from Azure to Sql Server. Second: Execute some Store procedures in the SQL Server 2005 instance. And third: Synchronize various tables from Sql Server to Azure sequentially.

You can use the Azure data sync, but its buggy - since I never managed to get it running flawlessly for even a week. It is still in [Preview mode with limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj590380.aspx).

Also, Data sync IMHO is suitable for database tables that deal with smaller volumes of changes per sync cycle.

If you dont want real time data sync, then I would suggest you to look into SSIS. Its much more flexible. I still use SSIS to move data from on-premise to Azure.

Alternatively, you can look into [Sync Framework - Replicating, Distributing, and Synchronizing Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868047.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Steps 1 and 3 should be fine with Data Sync. For step 2, you can't configure the service to execute something else for you, so you will have to invoke the sp yourself.

Comment: I tried using Sql Data Sync but says it can't be used in production environment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667301.aspx#bkmk_datasyncinproduction
I'm trying with Sync Framework