# Syncing data between onprem and Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, azure-sql-database, cloud

I have the following

**Scenario:** an on-premise SQL Server 2008 R2 and an app using it as db. I want to create an Azure SQL database that will be synced (**asynchronous replication**) with the on-premise instance. I do not want to have just a one-time migration like you can get with [SQL Database Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) - (if I understand it correctly).

**Goal:** I need to have the on-premise instance synced, let's say via daily job that will transfer the data, with my Azure SQL database.

Is it neccessary to setup **Azure Data Factory** for this? What about **Data Sync**? I can see that it is not available on the "new portal". Any advice how to approach this in a simple way would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: So, I have looked into the case of using [transactional replication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/) as Kin suggests. However it states only versions over SQL Server 2008. Any other ideas how to cope with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No .. Azure data factory is not required.

You can set up [transactional replication from on-prem to Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/). **Do not** use [data-sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) .. its [buggy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73661/8783) and have many issues.

Answer (score 1):

The [Azure SQL data synchronization tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) looks like the easiest way to synchronize your databases. The feature is available to all users on the Azure portal since July 1, 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in Mind that Azure Data Sync Does not accept computed columns in the tables involved in the data sync!